# PHP Form Validation

Tags: php, html

i am making a form to submit data, but the problem is that the errors are not echoed out. if all the fields are entered correctly the form successfully submits the data but when there's no data no error output is returned. i placed this echo statement just below the header

Here is the form ...

```
<label for="Name"> Names:</label>
                  <input type="text" name="Name" maxlength="25" size="24"  class="input"/>

<label for="Email">Email Address:</label>

                              <input type="text" name="Email" maxlength="30" size="24"  class="input"/>

<label for="Subject">Subject:</label><br/>
                              <input type="text" name="Subject" maxlength="25" size="25"  class="input"/>

<label for="Comments">Comments</label><br/>
                              <textarea rows="6"   cols="50" name="Ujumbe"size="140" class="textarea"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Send Mail" name="submit" />
```

and here is the validation code...

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ $error= array();

                   if(empty($_POST['Name'])) {  $error[]='Your  name ';  }
                     else if (!empty ($_POST['Name'])){ $Name=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['Name']));  }

                   if(empty($_POST['Email']))    {$error[]='Your  email address. ';  }

                      else if(preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/",$_POST['Email'])){
                           $Email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);
                          }
                           else {
                                 $error[]='That you entered e-mail address is invalid.';
                                }

                  if(empty($_POST['Comments'])){   $error[]='Enter a comment ';    }
                                         else if (!empty ($_POST['Comments']))
                                        {
                                         $Comments=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['Comments']));  
                                        }

                  if(empty($_POST['Subject'])){   $error[]='Enter the subject ';    }
                                                   else if (!empty ($_POST['Comments'])){ $Subject=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['Subject']));  }


      if (empty ($error)){

                header("messages.php?x=3");


                         }
       else{
             $error_message ='<br/><br/><span class="error"><br />You did not submit the following required information!<br/><br/>' ;
             foreach($error as $key => $values) {
                       $error_message.= "<br/>$values<br/>";
                }
                    $error_message.="</span> <br/><br/><br/>";
                            }}

?>
```

Comment: You don't have any `echo` statements. I would image that's your problem.

Comment: Please please please do everybody (including the future and the current you) a huge favor by properly indenting your code

Comment: Do you have this on a live site?

Comment: http://www.phpcodecleaner.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last part of your code to look like this:

```
if (empty ($error)){
        header("messages.php?x=3");
    } else {
        $error_message ='<br/><br/><span class="error"><br />You did not submit the following required information!<br/><br/>' ;
        foreach($error as $key => $values) {
            $error_message.= "<br/>$values<br/>";
        }

        $error_message.="</span> <br/><br/><br/>";

        echo 'Please see the below error Messages: <br>' . $error_message;
    }
```

Also, rather than adding countless `<br>` to your code, which are both *ugly* and *unnecessary*, you can simply create an un-ordered list, see below, and use `margins` to separate the list items.

```
            if (empty ($error)){
            header("messages.php?x=3");
        } else {
            $error_message ='<span class="error">You did not submit the following required information!</span>
<ul id="error-list">
' ;
            foreach($error as $key => $values) {
                $error_message.= "<li>$values</li>";
            }

            $error_message.="</ul>";

            echo 'Please see the below error Messages: <br>' . $error_message;
        }
```

CSS:

```
.error{
    margin: 15px 0 10px 0;
}

#error-list li{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```